# What is the main content of Backlight Remover (that red coat on the orange blinkers)?

Tags: cleaning

Can someone tell me which main content [Backlight Remover](https://www.nonpaints.com/en/motip-backlight-remover-in-150ml-aerosol) has? Several years ago I sprayed my orange blinkers in red and that worked but not for long. It seems to me it has no UV protection or there is another reason this stuff fades to white.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is manufactured by Motip Dupli, whose [product webpage](https://www.motip.com/products/motip/automotive/tuning-line/backlight-remover/) contains a [link to a specification sheet](https://www.motip.com/upload/motip_upload/lijnpdf/MSDS/EN/WEBL363.pdf) for this product.

The specification sheet indicates that the liquid content is *n-butyl-acetate*, and the gases used are *propane*, *butane*, and *isobutane*, with a less-than-1% content of *benzine.*

All these substances are very flammable.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I failed at that look up. Thank you man! Now could you or someone also explain to me where to get 'n-butyl-acetate' easy or something like diesel, gasoline, turpentine, wd-40 etc. would work (with or without some more tough rubbing) reason I ask is for MOT there is no real way back I can't show up with half cleaned reflectors.